# Django makemessages command throws error

Tags: python, django

When I am trying to run makemessages command I get following errors:

```
(bdm_app)bdm@bdm-VirtualBox:/webapps/bdm_app/bdm$ python manage.py makemessages -l nl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 283, in handle_noargs
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 299, in build_potfiles
    file_list = self.find_files(".")
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 358, in find_files
    ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT)]
  File "/webapps/bdm_app/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 342, in normpath
    initial_slashes = path.startswith('/')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I use virtualenv with django 1.7 installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Is one of settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT None?

Comment: It was! But now I get different error: http://pastebin.com/fE678zjF

Comment: I guess you did not set the source encoding of your Python files as described in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ .

Comment: @dease please check the given code is in the template:           #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-